# Example of norm of vectors in the Tsirelson space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I would like to know if there is some expression or estimate for the norm of vectors of the form $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n e_j$ in the Tsirelson space, where $(e_j)$ is the canonical basis.

Thank you!

Comment: Any Schreier subset of $n$ has cardinality  at most $k$  if $n = 2k $ or  $k+1$ for $n = 2k+1 $. This provides a lower estimation of the norm $k/ 2$ or $k+1/ 2 $. Is there any better lower estimation?

Comment: By "the Tsirelson space", do you mean Tsirelson's original space (which is asymptotic $c_0$) or the Figiel-Johnson Tsirelson space (which is asymptotic $\ell_1$)?

Comment: Let $W$ be the norming set for the $ F-J $ Tsirelson  space. Every $ f \in W $ not singleton is of the form $ \sum_{l=1} ^k { 1/2^l {\chi_{F_l}}}$ where  $({{F_l})_{l=1}^k} $ are pairwise disjoint and $F_l$ belongs to$ S_l $. We set $order(f) =l $ if  $l$  the maximum such that $F_l$ is non empty and $|x|_l =max  ( f(x) : order(f) = l ) $.  Set $ x_n = \sum _{j=1}^n {e_j } $ and the question is the following. Is the sequence $ ( |x_n |_l )_l $ a decreasing one?

Comment: @user469053 It would be interesting to know the answer for both spaces.

Comment: For the asymptotic $\ell_1$ space, I believe we get $\|\sum_{i=1}^{2n} e_i\|=\max \{1,n/2\}$ and $\|\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} e_i\|=\max\{1,(n+1)/2\}$, which is in line with the answer by @SArgyros. 

For the asymptotic $c_0$ space, I think the answer is much more complicated. It probably involves the Ackermann functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in W$ where $W$ is the norming set of the space and f is not a singleton. Then $f = 1/2 \sum_{j=1}^l {f_j} $ with $l\leq f_1 < ...< f_l $ all elements of $W$. Also $f$ has a representation as  $\sum_{q=1}^p {1/2^q} {\chi_{F_q}}$. If $p=1$ and $n= 4k$ then $f(x_n) \leq k$ and there exists an $f$ with $p=1$ such that $f(x_n) = k$. Assume that $p >1$ and set $r$ the cardinality of the set $( f_j : f_j = e_m )$ clearly $r\leq l- 1$. Then $|\cup_{q>1} {F_q}|\leq n-(l+r-1)  $.

Now $f(x_n) \leq \frac{n-(l+r-1)} {2^2} + \frac{r}{2} \leq \frac {n}{4}$